# How to add Action Bar from support library into PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, preferenceactivity, android-support-library

Action Bar compatibility has been added into support library, revision 18. It now has [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) class for creating activities with Action Bar on older versions of Android.

Is there any way to add Action Bar from support library into `PreferenceActivity`?

*Previously I used [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and it has `SherlockPreferenceActivity`.*

Comment: maybe still relevant: [ActionBar in PreferenceActivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928874/actionbar-in-preferenceactivity)

Comment: i just edited my answer, found a working preferencefragment implementation based on support-v4 that works great with ActionBarActivity. I`m using it by myself.

Comment: If you wish, you can use my solution :
https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialStuffLibrary

Answer (score 127, accepted):

EDIT: In appcompat-v7 22.1.0 Google added the AppCompatDelegate abstract class as a delegate you can use to extend AppCompat's support to any activity.

Use it like this:

```
...
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
...

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
        super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        getDelegate().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (mDelegate == null) {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }
}
```

No more hacking. Code taken from [AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/7200281446186c7192cb02f54dc2b38e02d705e5/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).

Comment: please put your essential code snippets in your answer. to avoid potential broken link issue.

Comment: thanks, this works for me - i'd change new LinearLayout in the first inflate call to: ``(ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()``

Comment: Works for me too and helped me recover the settings title which got lost when upgrading to release 21.

Comment: This works for me to bring the ActionBar back into preference activity after upgrading to release 21. I use `mActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.icon);` to show my app icon instead of the app name.

Comment: This doesn't work with nested <PreferenceScreen> elements. Nested preference screens have no Toolbar.

Comment: @petrsyn It actually works. Look [here](https://github.com/Frozen-Developers/android-cache-cleaner/blob/master/CacheCleaner/src/main/java/com/frozendevs/cache/cleaner/activity/SettingsActivity.java) and [here](https://github.com/Frozen-Developers/android-cache-cleaner/blob/master/CacheCleaner/src/main/res/xml/settings.xml) to find out how you should do it.

Comment: @Ľubomír Kučera Thanks for answering. Your solution creates nested PreferenceScreen manually in the onCreate() method of the PreferenceActivity child class. My comment was about using <PreferenceScreen> nested under another <PreferenceScreen> in the prefs.xml. This stopped working in AppCompat v21. This used to work in older versions of AppCompat lib and also in the ActionBarSherlock lib. Anyway, thanks for responding.

Comment: If I use <style name="Theme.Application" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" /> then my Settings text is black on dark gray. What is the simplest way to fix this?

Comment: @swooby You might suffer from [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78819) bug.

Comment: @petrsyn I have solved the nesting problem here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27455363/566127

Comment: Any idea why ListPreferences radio button stop working after applying this approach? (android 4.0.3).

Comment: When I commented out the //getDelegate().installViewFactory(); ListPreference started to work. Strange behaviour.

Comment: @ĽubomírKučera This gives me almost completely 2.x look. Ok, checkboxes are material style but everything else is old. What is the point of this then?

Comment: @petrsyn: I have problem like you. How can i fix it? I tried in the way of Ľubomír Kučerabut, but it did not work.

Comment: Okay so where do I put the toolbar in the xml? I'm getting a NullPointerException

Answer (score 78):

There is currently no way to achieve with AppCompat. I've opened a bug internally.

Comment: @Maarten the link doesn't work with current support library, there would be probably much more work involved to make your own.

Comment: @Chris, do you have any idea when we could expect `PreferenceActivity` to be added to `ActionBarCompat`?

Comment: @nsL I still remember that being a problem, and how ABS solved it neatly. But I wouldn't get my hopes up, as some important issues were declined back then. Disappointment.

Comment: I think it is very unlikely that this feature is going to be implemented. Number of devices running older versions of Android (< 4.0) is less than 30% at this point, and this number is going down every month.

Comment: @Chris can you provide a bug id, so I can follow progress on that thing?

Comment: This was entered almost a year ago and no resolution??

Comment: w.t.f still waiting??

Comment: It wasn't probably possible at that time but now I got it to work without any 'workarounds'. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25603448/1276636

Comment: This answer is outdated, today there is a solution, see @Ľubomír Kučera 's answer

Comment: One of the thousands of bugs;-)

Answer (score 24):

I have managed to create a workaround similar to what the Google Play Store uses. [Link to Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455330/566127)

### Please find the GitHub Repo: **[Here](https://github.com/davcpas1234/MaterialSettings)**

---

Very Similar to your own code but added xml to allow for set title:

Continuing to use `PreferenceActivity`:

`settings_toolbar.xml :`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/action_settings"
    />
```

`SettingsActivity.java :`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
        Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
        root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
        bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

`Result :`

[image: example]

---

## **UPDATE (Gingerbread Compatibility) :**

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564400/creating-a-preference-screen-with-support-v21-toolbar/27455330?noredirect=1#comment43790647_27455330), Gingerbread Devices are returning NullPointerException on this line:

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
```

### FIX:

`SettingsActivity.java :`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toolbar bar;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
            bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
            root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
        } else {
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            ListView content = (ListView) root.getChildAt(0);

            root.removeAllViews();

            bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
            

            int height;
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
                height = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }else{
                height = bar.getHeight();
            }

            content.setPadding(0, height, 0, 0);

            root.addView(content);
            root.addView(bar);
        }

        bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any issues with the above let me know!

---

**UPDATE 2: TINTING WORKAROUND**

As pointed out in many dev notes `PreferenceActivity` does not support tinting of elements, however by utilising a few internal classes you CAN achieve this. That is until these classes are removed. (Works using appCompat support-v7 v21.0.3).

Add the following imports:

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintCheckBox;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintCheckedTextView;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintRadioButton;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintSpinner;
```

Then override the `onCreateView` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // Allow super to try and create a view first
    final View result = super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // If we're running pre-L, we need to 'inject' our tint aware Views in place of the
        // standard framework versions
        switch (name) {
            case "EditText":
                return new TintEditText(this, attrs);
            case "Spinner":
                return new TintSpinner(this, attrs);
            case "CheckBox":
                return new TintCheckBox(this, attrs);
            case "RadioButton":
                return new TintRadioButton(this, attrs);
            case "CheckedTextView":
                return new TintCheckedTextView(this, attrs);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

`Result:`

[image: example 2]

---

### *AppCompat 22.1*

AppCompat 22.1 introduced new tinted elements, meaning that there is no longer a need to utilise the internal classes to achieve the same effect as the last update. Instead follow this (still overriding `onCreateView`):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // Allow super to try and create a view first
    final View result = super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // If we're running pre-L, we need to 'inject' our tint aware Views in place of the
        // standard framework versions
        switch (name) {
            case "EditText":
                return new AppCompatEditText(this, attrs);
            case "Spinner":
                return new AppCompatSpinner(this, attrs);
            case "CheckBox":
                return new AppCompatCheckBox(this, attrs);
            case "RadioButton":
                return new AppCompatRadioButton(this, attrs);
            case "CheckedTextView":
                return new AppCompatCheckedTextView(this, attrs);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

**NESTED PREFERENCE SCREENS**

A lot of people are experiencing issues with including the Toolbar in nested `<PreferenceScreen />`s however, I have found a solution!! - After a lot of trial and error!

Add the following to your `SettingsActivity`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
    super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);

    // If the user has clicked on a preference screen, set up the screen
    if (preference instanceof PreferenceScreen) {
        setUpNestedScreen((PreferenceScreen) preference);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setUpNestedScreen(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
    final Dialog dialog = preferenceScreen.getDialog();

    Toolbar bar;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent();
        bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
        root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
    } else {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        ListView content = (ListView) root.getChildAt(0);

        root.removeAllViews();

        bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);

        int height;
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            height = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }else{
            height = bar.getHeight();
        }

        content.setPadding(0, height, 0, 0);

        root.addView(content);
        root.addView(bar);
    }

    bar.setTitle(preferenceScreen.getTitle());

    bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

The reason that `PreferenceScreen`'s are such a pain is because they are based as a wrapper dialog, so we need to capture the dialog layout to add the toolbar to it.

---

### Toolbar Shadow

By design importing the `Toolbar` does not allow for elevation and shadowing in pre-v21 devices, so if you would like to have elevation on your `Toolbar` you need to wrap it in a `AppBarLayout`:

`settings_toolbar.xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       .../>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Not forgetting to add the add the Design Support library as a dependency in `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

---

### Android 6.0

I have investigated the reported overlapping issue and I cannot reproduce the issue.

The full code in use as above produces the following:

[image]

If I am missing something please let me know via [this repo](https://github.com/davcpas1234/MaterialSettings) and I will investigate.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm :)

Comment: Why does this not work for the nested PreferenceScreen, but only for the main PreferenceScreen?

Comment: @Tobi I have updated my answer to solve the nested issue, and explained why. `:)`

Comment: Thanks! Your advice "AppCompat 22.1" did the trick for me :) Very useful!

Comment: @DavidPassmore why i cant see shadow on api 10 when i wrap toolbar with appbarlayout ?

Comment: @DavidPassmore why wrap it inside AppBarLayout for shadow if it works v21+ ? why not Just use "elevation"?

Comment: why is `PreferenceActivity` *such a pain in the ass to use* ??? it's supposed to save time. I might as well make a regular activity and manually lay out all the settings in a linear layout myself. Fuuuuck !

Comment: In Android API 24, in NESTED PREFERENCE SCREENS, in this line (        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent();
) I'm getting this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout. Is any solution for this???

Comment: Hi @D.O. can you raise this on the GitHub so I can track the errors :)

Comment: Hi @David, you mean in this github link, isn't it? https://github.com/davcpas1234/MaterialSettings

Comment: Done! raise in GitHub

Answer (score 12):

Found a PreferenceFragment implementation based on support-v4 Fragment:

https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

Edit: I just tested it and its working great!

Comment: @Konstantin, can you add some code example? I downloaded it, changed the import from android.preference.PreferenceFragment to android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment, and I see it added some headers in the middle of the screen, but not the ActionBar on the top

Comment: It doesnt add the actionbar thats the activity's job. Unfortunally i have no samplecode at hand but it should work similar to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

Answer (score 3):

Integrating `PreferenceActivity` with ABC is not possible, at least for me. I tried the two possibilities I could find but none worked:

### Option 1:

`ActionBarPreferenceActivity` extends `PreferenceActivity`. When you do this you get restricted by `ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivity activity)`. Also you need to implement `ActionBar.Callbacks` which is not accessible

### Option 2:

`ActionBarPreferenceActivity` extends `ActionBarActivity`. This approach requires rewriting a whole new `PreferenceActivity`, `PreferenceManager` and may be `PreferenceFragment` which means you need access to hidden classes like `com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils`
The solution to this can only come from Google devs implementing an `ActionBarWrapper` that can be added to any activity.

If you really need a preference activity, my advice for now is `ActionBarSherlock`.

However, I managed to implement it [here](https://gist.github.com/mburumaxwell/8254359).

Comment: Per4.0 brings crash. I've forked it and improved .  https://gist.github.com/0e9fe2119b901921b160

Comment: Check my solution. It doesn't use any workaround http://stackoverflow.com/a/25603448/1276636

Comment: It does not solve anything! Hope you understand the issue at hand

Answer (score 3):

### Problem Background:

The OP wants to know how can we put `MenuItem`s in the `ActionBar` of `PreferenceActivity` for pre-Honeycomb because Android's support library has a bug which doesn't allow this to happen.

### My Solution:

I've found a much cleaner way, than already proposed, to achieve the target (and found it in the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent)):

> `android:parentActivityName`
>
> The class name of the logical parent of the
>   activity. The name here must match the class name given to the
>   corresponding  element's android:name attribute.
>
> The system reads this attribute to determine which activity should be
>   started when the use presses the Up button in the action bar. The
>   system can also use this information to synthesize a back stack of
>   activities with TaskStackBuilder.
>
> To support API levels 4 - 16, you can also declare the parent activity
>   with a  element that specifies a value for
>   "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY". For example:
>
> ```
> <activity
>     android:name="com.example.app.ChildActivity"
>     android:label="@string/title_child_activity"
>     android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
>     <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 4+ -->
>     <meta-data
>         android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
>         android:value="com.example.app.MainActivity" />
> </activity>
> ```

Now do what you would normally do in your `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Since it's a part of Android Docs, it has no side-affects.

Happy coding. :)

### Update:

This solution no longer works if you're targeting Lollipop. If you're using AppCompat, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455363/1276636) answer is what you should be looking for.

Comment: How does this help get the action bar in Preference activity?

Comment: @ArjunU. easy solution - try it and figure it out.

Comment: @ArjunU. The problem was that the `PreferencesActivity` wouldn't have any way to put items to `ActionBar`, especially the back button. My answer is a good fix for that.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Any explanation how I could improve my answer or what was wrong?

Comment: @ArjunU. I have updated my answer. Kindly remove your down vote.

Comment: @Sufian Thanks for linking to my answer, glad it's helping everyone `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get `android.app.Actionbar` by using `getActionBar()`. It returned a null value at first... then I went to the manifest and changed the theme to:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Then I was able to have the actionbar again. I'm assuming this will only work for certain build levels. So you might want to do a check for the build number or check if the value returned is null.

It'll be fine for me because the app I'm working on is for `ICS/4.0`+.

Comment: Here's a simpler solution, one which doesn't uses any workarounds http://stackoverflow.com/a/25603448/1276636

Answer (score 0):

Now the official answer for this problem has been released. It is the [v7/v14 Preference Support](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-preference) library.

See [How to use the v7/v14 Preference Support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070186/how-to-use-the-v7-v14-preference-support-library) for the discussion how to use it.