# getActionBar from Fragment with AppCompatLibrary

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'm look for the easiest way to get an ActionBar instance from a Fragment using AppCompatLibrary and API 8.

Already tried things like

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar()
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to cast it:

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
```

Comment: Any clue to get it from PreferenceActivity please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849193/how-to-add-action-bar-from-support-library-into-preferenceactivity

Comment: convert to AppCompatActivity and you won't have problems except you don't use AppCompatActivity