# No shadow by default on Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm updating my app with the new Toolbar from the support library v21. My problem is that the toolbar does not cast any shadow if I don't set the "elevation" attribute. Is that the normal behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

My code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:elevation="4dp"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
       app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       .
       .
       .
```

And in my Activity - OnCreate method:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Are you seeing this on a device running Lollipop?

Comment: On a device running Lollipop shows the shadow because of the elevation attribute but not on KitKat or older versions. Thats the expected behavior for the elevation attribute as documentation says, but I was expecting that, by default without the elevation attribute, the shadow would cast like it does the Action Bar on every version.

Comment: I posted a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759202/553905

Comment: Use /values folders and styles.xml to apply the proper shadow code based on OS version (see below).

Answer (score 262, accepted):

I ended up setting my own drop shadow for the toolbar, thought it might helpful for anyone looking for it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                       android:background="@color/color_alizarin"
                                       android:titleTextAppearance="@color/White"
                                       app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- **** Place Your Content Here **** -->

        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="5dp"
              android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
              android:endColor="#88333333"
              android:angle="90"/>

</shape>
```

@color/color_alizarin

```
<color name="color_alizarin">#e74c3c</color>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to hide your view if the device you are running is >= to Lollipop, if not you'll end up with two shadows.

Comment: Excellent solution! I was struggling trying to achieve a consistent look for the toolbar between Lollipop and previous versions. Now it's perfect.

Comment: @dragon who spits fire it worked, but View is below every content in xml but when i run it is on top, i'm curious why

Comment: This is the wrong way to to it because you'll have to remove that view for 5.0 layouts. Use android:windowContentOverlay or android:foreground instead.

Comment: From Google about designing the [Toolbar material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/objects-in-3d-space.html#objects-in-3d-space-elevation-android-), you should set `android:layout_height="4dp"` for the height of shadow, instead of `5dp`. Actually, elevation is the same as the height of shadow you set on `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this solution because I inflate my activities layout into the frame layout in your example, can you think of a way for this to work?

Comment: Recommending using "android:endColor="#c7c7c7" over android:endColor="#88333333"

Comment: @ZachSperske use relative layout instead like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30171360/5223160

Comment: i think you updated your answer without removing @color/color_alizarin

Comment: @MohammadFaisal that's a lot better on Note 8 since the alternative has a black line at the top. Would this work on non white backgrounds though? seems too light

Comment: I recommend using a black shadow instead of gray: `android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"` and `android:endColor="#32000000"`

Comment: Please remember that gradient is not shadow.

Answer (score 223):

Google released the Design Support library a few weeks ago and there is a nifty solution for this problem in this library.

Add the Design Support library as a dependency in `build.gradle` :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Add `AppBarLayout` supplied by the library as a wrapper around your `Toolbar` layout to generate a drop shadow.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           .../>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here is the result :

[image]

There are lots of other tricks with the design support library.

1. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en
2. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

## AndroidX

As above but with dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

and `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`

Comment: Setting the `AppBarLayout` as a wrapper around the `Toolbar` doesn't set any shadow for me. Note that I don't use a navigation drawer. Any ideas on why it doesn't work?

Comment: @avb1994 Can't say for sure, I have tested it without a nav drawer. Can you post it as a question with the layout file?

Comment: see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115531/add-elevation-shadow-on-toolbar-for-pre-lollipop-devices thanks for your comment

Comment: You don't need this two lines compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0', because compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' depends on them

Comment: Do note this only works for lollipop and above. It won't work pre lollipop since underneath it's just using ViewCompat.setElevation().

Comment: As far as I know, with the design lib you can simply set elevation now.

Comment: Questions says "Toolbar", not "AppBarLayout"

Comment: @vortal `Toolbar` is placed inside `AppBarLayout`, take a look one more time

Comment: @avb unfortunately it works for Android 21 and higher only

Comment: Also note, that depending on your layout, you may also need to add `android:clipChildren="false"`, to your parent(s) of `AppBarLayout`, otherwise shadow can get cut out

Answer (score 28):

You can't use the elevation attribute before API 21 (Android Lollipop). You can however add the shadow programmatically, for example using a custom view placed below the Toolbar.

@layout/toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
```

@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#88333333"
        android:angle="90"/> </shape>
```

in your activity layout
    `<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />`

[image]

Comment: Can you fix `@layout/toolbar` example with full layout file?

Comment: Why does @layout/toolbar have two root views? Can you provide the full example please?

Answer (score 19):

Use */values* folders to apply the correct shadow style based on OS version.

**For under 5.0 devices**, use */values/styles.xml* to add *windowContentOverlay* to the body of your activity:

```
<style name="MyViewArea">
    <item name="android:foreground">?android:windowContentOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Then add your own custom shadow by changing your Theme to include:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/bottom_shadow</item>
```

You can grab Google's IO app shadow resource here: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/bottom_shadow.9.png

**For 5.0 devices & later**, use */values-v21/styles.xml* to add *elevation* to your toolbar using a custom header style:

```
<style name="MyViewArea">
</style>

<style name="MyToolbar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Note that in the second case, I had to create an empty *MyViewArea* style so the *windowContentOverlay* wouldn't show up too.

[Update: changed resource names and added Google shadow.]

Comment: May I know what is MyBody and MyHeader? Where I should apply them?

Comment: I updated the names: MyHeader is now MyToolbar and MyBody is MyViewArea. You can assign styles in xml layouts like this: style="@style/MyToolbar".

Comment: What is MyViewArea applied to?

Comment: Your page / body / view area.

Comment: I think `android:foreground` only works on FrameLayout before API 23.

Comment: Thanks!...I forgot what I did before to have the shadow and this post reminded me!....its android:background attribute of the toolbar ppl!!

Also I had set the app:elevation (my min sdk was 21) and thus was wondering why it wasn't working, since my toolbar was inflated programmatically, I forgot that the underlying container which encompasses my toolbar and rest of the view had a background...not sure if it was transparent which might have caused the isssue.

Answer (score 14):

If you are seting the `ToolBar` as `ActionBar` then just call:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(YOUR_ELEVATION);
```

Note: This must be called after `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: Is it just me, or does the navigation drawer reset the elevation of the toolbar? I"ve tried to set it to 0, and it worked, but then when I drag the navigation drawer, I see it has a shadow again...

Comment: `setElevation()` is defined only for API-21+ though.

Comment: @Sebastian The support actionbar elevation works for previous APIs too.

Comment: Internally that uses `ViewCompat.setElevation()` and thus will only work on API 21 and up.

Comment: Use android:windowContentOverlay or android:foreground for under API 21.

Comment: What is the default elevation?

Comment: This is best solution so far (It doesn't solve for pre-lollipop devices but that is not a big issue now)

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me very well:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: How can this work if on pre lollipop cardview pads itself in order to draw the shadow? This is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/BIj8env.png this answer worked for me and it doesn't suffer from the drawbacks from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575197/no-shadow-by-default-on-toolbar/30171360#30171360

Comment: Actually, you're better off with the AppBarLayout as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31026359/1451716
My answer is old, before the AppBarLayout was released

Comment: Is this even legal? It's not supposed to be used with Toolbar. OMG!

Answer (score 9):

i added

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
...
android:translationZ="5dp"/>
```

in toolbar description and it works for me.
Using 5.0+

Answer (score 7):

> My problem is that the toolbar does not cast any shadow if I don't set the "elevation" attribute. Is that the normal behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

That's the normal behavior. Also see the FAQ at the end of [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Answer (score 7):

Was toying with this for hours, here's what worked for me.

Remove all the `elevation` attributes from the `appBarLayout` and `Toolbar` widgets (including `styles.xml` if you are applying any styling).

Now inside activity,apply the `elvation` on your `actionBar`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(3.0f);
```

This should work.

Comment: What if I want the elevation on the AppBarLayout, as it can collapse/expand ?

Comment: `setElevation` takes a parameter as pixels. You have to convert it appropriately, e.g. `(int) (3.0 / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density)`

Answer (score 6):

All you need is a `android:margin_bottom` equal to the `android:elevation` value. No `AppBarLayout`, `clipToPadding`, etc. required.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Inner layout goes here-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: nothing worked, except this, right on point and make sense too

Answer (score 4):

You can also make it work with `RelativeLayout`. This reduces layout nesting a little bit ;)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **background** color and **elevation** togather.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
     app:elevation="8dp"
     android:elevation="8dp"
     android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my situation elevation doesn't work well because I haven't given any background to the toolbar. Try giving background color to the toolbar then set elevation and it will work well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:buttonGravity="center_vertical" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most solutions work fine here. Would like to show another, similar alternative :

gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

You layout can have a Toolbar View, and a shadow for it, below, similar to this (need modification of course) :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_action_bar_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**res/drawable-v21/toolbar_action_bar_shadow.xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/msl__action_bar_shadow"/>
```

**res/drawable/toolbar_action_bar_shadow.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay" tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```

**res/drawable/msl__action_bar_shadow.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#00000000"
                android:startColor="#33000000" />

            <size android:height="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar as Toolbar)
    }
}
```

Full sample [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115828845), as I've noticed the IDE has a bug of saying `foreground` attribute is too new to be used here.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer will be to add
**android:backgroundTint="#ff00ff"**
to the tool bar
with 
**android:background="@android:color/white"**

If you use other color then white for the background it will remove the shadow.
Nice one Google!

Answer (score 0):

actionbar_background.xml

```
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/black"
                android:centerColor="@color/black"
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="3dp" >
        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

add to actionbar_style background

```
<style name="Theme.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
```

name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle|showCustom

add to Basetheme

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/home_back</item>
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For 5.0 + : You can use AppBarLayout with Toolbar. AppBarLayout has "elevation" attribure.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: What about previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with the shadow. The shadow is drawn by direct parent of AppBarLayout in my case. If height of the parent is the same as AppBarLayout's the shadow cannot be drawn. So checking size of the parent layout and maybe layout remake can solve the problem. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6xddb0/having_a_toolbar_as_a_fragment_the_shadow/

Answer (score 0):

**I am posting this because this took me hours to find so i hope it may help someone.**

I had a problem that the shadow/elevation was not showing though i created a simple activity and placed the toolbar as follows:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mt_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="12dp"/>
```

**It turns out that in the manifest
setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` was causing it! once i removed it, the shadow appeared**

Answer (score 0):

```
Just put  background
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:background="#fff"

                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```