# Default action bar elevation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to use an elevation in a custom layout element and I want to set in XML the value of that element using the default action bar elevation value. I can't find a way to get it in XML and I'd like to avoid to call `getElevation()` in code. Any tips?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Default value is 8dp, create dimen with this value and use on whole project, I got it from sources, but [the material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#) state the action bar elevation should be 4dp.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't exist somewhere? How did you find this value?

Comment: @KirillShalnov I see. How come setting the elevation on a toolbar that was set as the action bar - doesn't do anything? I've tried setting it to 0 on some cases and 8dp on others, but it doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: @androiddeveloper you can change elevetion programmaticaly on Lollipop. To older version you should to `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">null</item>` in your style.xml to disable shadow, I understand the question?

Comment: @KirillShalnov Can you please try it? For some reason, when using the support library's toolbar (and use setSupportActionBar), I can't find out how to hide/show its shadow via code. "setElevation" doesn't work on both the toolbar and the action bar (on Lollipop).

Comment: @androiddeveloper `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.la_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);` I tried. No shadow. may be if you have shadow it is not from toolbar, set windowContentOverlay - null

Comment: @KirillShalnov Sorry, I forgot I used my own shadow solution, so it doesn't do anything when using an elevation. I used a layout below the toolbar, which is an imageView for Lollipop and above (with some drawable), and a FrameLayout with android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay" for before Lollipop. Hiding and showing the shadow there is by hiding/showing this view. I've even made a post about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27474766/878126

Comment: @KirillShalnov The material design guidelines state the action bar elevation should be 4dp: http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/objects-in-3d-space.html#objects-in-3d-space-elevation

Comment: @ashughes I got it from sources

Comment: If the elevation property is not working, it's a known issue. You need to set your view to have a solid background before it works: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78248

Comment: The default value is clearly 4dp, not 8dp. I don't know which "sources" you checked, but the [dimens.xml in the appcompat design library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/res/values/dimens.xml#56) clearly states `<dimen name="design_appbar_elevation">4dp</dimen>`

Comment: @ChristianGarcía it was two years ago. Do you think for two years nothing has changed, but I still remember where I spied on these values?

Comment: I confirm that the default ActionBar elevation in AppCompat is still 8dp: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml#42
But the App Bar elevation in the design support library is 4dp, so there is definitely an inconsistency here.

Comment: After some investigation, it turns out the default action bar elevation in the OS material themes changed from 8dp (Android 5) to 4dp (Android 6).
I raised an issue on the Android bug tracker and the next version of AppCompat will use a default value of 4dp for the default ActionBar instead of 8dp currently. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219400

Comment: @BladeCoder please, edit answer, and I will apply changes

Answer (score 13):

The standard elevation of the app bar is **4dp** according to material design spec. Here is the link:
https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows

Answer (score 5):

The default elevation of the action bar is **4dp**. I did a little experiment by creating one custom view right below the action bar and set its elevation to **4dp**. So, both were looking the same. Official documentation also mentioned **4dp** standard elevation for the action bar.

> 1. Nav drawer: 16dp
> 2. App bar: 4dp
> 3. Card: 1dp to 8dp
> 4. FAB: 6dp
> 5. Button: 2dp to 8dp
> 6. Dialog: 24dp

Here *App bar* refers to *Action bar*.

Reference: [Elevation](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-shadows-shadows)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android) is the official resource available for the elevations.

Answer (score 0):

The default elevation of `AppBarLayout` is `@dimen/design_appbar_elevation` (which is `4dp`). `Actionbar` has `@dimen/abc_action_bar_elevation_material` as default elevation (which is `4dp` as well).

These values can be found in `stateListAnimator` of `Widget.Design.AppBarLayout` and the parent of `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar` respectively. The `Toolbar` doesn't seem to have any default elevation.