# Android elevation property not working in list view on emulator but its showing correct output in android studio?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

The problem is that i want to show a card view like custom view inside a list view.
the view is showing fine in emulator but its not showing the same in emulator.

Here is the link to the image in which both preview can be seen simultaneously.

[image]

Code for list view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/custom_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
tools:listitem="@layout/listlayout">
</ListView>
```

Code for custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:elevation="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/productImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />



        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/product_title"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="shortDescription"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_body_1_material"
            android:id="@+id/shortDescription" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="price"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="newPrice"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/newPrice"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Buy"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:id="@+id/buy"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: maybe try running it on a device

Comment: Post your card xml file

Comment: Updated the code please help asap

Answer (score 5):

You need to add one more parent layout on LinerLayout. There add property `android:clipToPadding="false"`. For more read this reply [Android "elevation" not showing a shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

in XML of CardView try this:

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: I have not used the card view its a list view in which i want to have a custom view .

Comment: On Lollipop it works setting elevation. For pre-Lollipop, you need to implement shadows by yourself. Which API version your Emulator is running ?

Comment: i have been trying to run the app on api 21 and 22 ie 4.4.4 and 5.1 but no luck on any of the mentioned

Comment: use any view with the gradient in xml of your listview item to show something like shadow.