# How to add shadow at bottom only of recyclerview in android

Tags: android

Hi I am working on android app where I want to set shadow of RecyclerView at the bottom only. Right now it is something like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/topRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

How can I do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: shadow at every items of recyclerview?

Comment: I have horizontal recyclerview so I want a shadow on bottom of only recyclerview,

Comment: Can't you do this using framelayout ?

Comment: Anyone looking for answer, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412771/how-to-properly-set-elevation-value-to-recyclerview