# elevation not working in LinearLayout

Tags: android

bg_book_promotion is the picture which needs to have a shadow
when I add the `android:elevation`, it is not working.
which one can tell me how to correct it, it is so strange.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_fff_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_promotion_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin7"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin7"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin14"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_book_promotion"
            android:elevation="@dimen/height2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding9">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_promotion_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/color_fff_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize15"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_promotion_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/color_fff_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize12"
                tools:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot ?

Comment: `android:elevation` works with the lollipop and above Android OS.

Comment: device is above lollipop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elevation not working on a LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417049/elevation-not-working-on-a-linearlayout)

Comment: Attach screenshot of output at your end.

Comment: screenshot has been uploaded

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow

Answer (score 4):

just add android:outlineProvider="bounds"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_promotion_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin9"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin7"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin7"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin14"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_book_promotion"
    android:elevation="@dimen/height2"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding9">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use CardView as parent of Linear Layout, you will get elevation.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_fff_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_promotion_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin7"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin7"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin14"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_book_promotion"
            android:elevation="@dimen/height2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding9">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_promotion_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/color_fff_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize15"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_promotion_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/color_fff_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize12"
                tools:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```