# Add shadow to bottom of view

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been having a lot of trouble with this layout.

Basically I have 2 linears, one that is slightly grey with that shadow on bottom and below another linear just white. My trouble here is adding that shadow to the end of the first linear. I tried "elevation" but that is now what i need since i want the shadow to be inside the linear kinda if the last 10dp are from a different color but I'm not getting it right.

[image]

This is my layout so far, i thought of putting a view inside the first linear but its not working that good.

Any ideas how to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#f8f8f8"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:layout_width="312dp"
            android:layout_height="204dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"/> 
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below line in the `linearlayout` under which your `cardview` is sitting.

`android:elevation="8dp"`

Let the `cardElevation` part in your `cardView` be as it is.

```
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

Also just a suggestion :

If you're using `android:layout_weight` in both child `linearLayout` put `android:weightSum="2"` in your parent `linearLayout`  as mentioned in answer given by @Ming Leung [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

For more information on `android:weightSum="2"` you can refer to answers on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417049/elevation-not-working-on-a-linearlayout)

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615468/how-to-add-shadow-on-cardview-aligned-to-bottom-of-parent) would help you for `elevation` in `cardview`

Hope that helps.

Comment: i probably lead to some confusion, so i will edit the image, my cardview is fine the problem is the shadow in the linear where the cardview is.

Comment: Hi @Hugo check  out my updated answer, let me know if you've any other queries.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using a ConstraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="204dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]