# Android Elevation not working in LinearLayout Android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, shadow, android-elevation

I have Linear Layout, inside that i have recycler view. I want elevation and corner radius but it not working properly. Can someone suggest me what i am doing wrong.

**MainLayout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        style="@style/WhiteBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RecyclerView Item Layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

  .....more elements..

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**styles**

```
<style name="WhiteBox" >
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_box_background</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
</style>
```

**white_box_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="7dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

As **below image** show what i am getting, corner and shadow also not showing properly
[image]

**What I want i.e. Expected Result**

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use card view instead.

Add the dependency to your app module's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
}
```

Replace your current LinearLayout snippet with

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

for more info on CardView see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview#kts

Comment: I changed to **cardview** but also not working it same. I tried **cardUseCompatPadding** it works but added some margin in **start** and **end** side. It looks ugly. @Tajwane

Answer (score 0):

Try to add android:clipToPadding="false" to the parent ConstraintLayout which is holding the elevated view. Please see the accepted answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417049/elevation-not-working-on-a-linearlayout) for more details.

Comment: I already added android:clipToPadding="false but nothing works @ramona.cristea