# DrawerLayout setDrawerShadow and setDrawerElevation both not working (support 23.0.1)

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library

I'm trying to set a shadow on my navigation drawer after updating the support library but for some reason nothing is working and I'm stumped.

I came across this issue but it's solution is to just use setElevation which is also not working for me: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184434

There really isn't much code to post but here's what I'm talking about for reference:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerElevation(25f);
} else {
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.left_drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
}
```

I'm using a ScrimInsetsFrameLayout but that shouldn't be causing the issue AFAIKT.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you run app on lollipop+?

Comment: Yeah tested on devices running marshmallow and a Samsung phone running 4.4, same results on both

Comment: Show us screenshot? Also you can try sample app: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip This app should have drawer shadow, I think, so you'll be able to test it on your devices.

Comment: @krossovochkin that sample is out of date actually, I did take a look at that before asking

Answer (score 5):

What might have happened:

Since support lib 23 v21+ devices ignore custom drawables in this case. The the native built in elevation shadows are used. See: [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184434)

Here is the kicker though: transparent elements have no shadow.

By default the elevation shadow is drawn from the views background-outline. If the view has no background, the shadow won't show up.

If your view doesn't have its own background, using the outline Provider e.g.:

```
android:outlineProvider="bounds"
```

should do the trick. The doc can be found here [ViewOutlineProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html). 
In short:

> Interface by which a View builds its Outline, used for shadow casting and clipping.

Some more information and in-depth explanation is here: [Android "elevation" not showing a shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow)

Comment: I'll try this for sure, my drawer layout definitely has a background but you never know