# Android ScrollView clipping child elevation shadow

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-elevation

As the title states, I'm trying to put a CardView inside a ScrollView, but the CardView elevation shadow is being but off by it's parent...

This is the Layout XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestScrollViewActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

The only workaround that I found is to add a padding to the parent ScrollView or add a margin to the child CardView...

Is there any option to prevent this from happening without using a padding/margin?

Thanks.

Edit:

This is how the layout looks like without setting a padding on the parent scroll view, as it can be seen, the left and right shadows are being cut off:
[image: Child's side shadow being cut off by parent scroll view]

Now, if a padding is added to the parent scrollview sides, the shadows are being drawn correctly as it can be seen here:
[image: Child's side shadow now shown correctly after adding padding to right and left side of scrollview]

So, my main question here is this the only way to achieve that?, or there is a tag or a configuration on the parent view that allow to correctly draw it's children views?

Comment: please share the screenshot of layout what it looks like and how you want it to look.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

this just worked for me in a similar problem:

> the right way to get a child view to show shadow is to set padding on the parent and set android:clipToPadding="false" on that parent.

as found here: [Android "elevation" not showing a shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow)

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that's the only way for now.

Comment: Great! This expands the list shadow and doesn't take padding into account, just as needed.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot. Still relevant in mid 2020.

Answer (score 61):

I was facing the same problem, I solved it by adding **cardUseCompatPadding** attribute to the card view:

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

The shadow will not be cut out or cropped after using this solution.

Comment: thank you it's worked for me.
But I have an issue regarding space while I put this line. Any idea why space increase

Comment: this just adds padding so the parent no longer crops the shadow, but if you don't want padding this is no good

Answer (score -4):

**This work for me adding cardUseCompatPadding attribute to the card view:**

set `android:clipToPadding="false"` on that parent.