# ListView SetAdapter() Layout issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-inflate

here is the problem.
I have a listview and a bunch of array-strings. I want to fill the listview with one textview for each string. the strings are injected but after injection the layout does not repsect the one that I have defined in tip_row.xml (in particular i cannot see any margins and elevation)

Here is the code:

TipsFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentActivity superActivity = super.getActivity();
    lLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tips_fragment, container, false);

    String[] general_tips = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.general_tips);
    List<String> tips = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(general_tips));
    tv = (TextView)lLayout.findViewById(R.id.general_tip_header);
    tv.setText("Advises");
    lv = (ListView)lLayout.findViewById(R.id.general_tips_list_view);
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(superActivity, R.layout.tip_row, tips); //the layout is tip_row
    lv.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    String[] noobs_tips = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.noob_tips);
    //tips.clear();
    tips.addAll(Arrays.asList(noobs_tips));

    String[] pro_tips = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pro_tips);
    //tips.clear();
    tips.addAll(Arrays.asList(pro_tips));

    //overrideFonts(superActivity, container);
    return lLayout;
}
```

tips_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/general_tip_header"
    layout="@layout/tips_header"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/general_tips_list_view"></ListView></LinearLayout>
```

tips_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="General Problems" />
```

tip_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tip_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:elevation="9dp"/>
```

Note that in tip_row.xml I have defined `android:elevation` and `android:layout_margin` but this two attribute are not rendered by my app.

Here you can find a screenshot: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiCrf.jpg)

PS: I can succesfully change the font-size or the padding, the only things that does not work are elevation and the margin for this row items. Elevation does not work either in tips_header.xml

Thanks

Comment: The elevation field will only work for newer Android versions, I believe Lollipop and above.

Comment: Currently i am developing with API 23 and I am debugging with an android 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Add a parent `RelativeLayout` to your `TextView` element and set `android:clipToPadding="false"` to parent.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tip_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:elevation="9dp"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

For more info check [@Justin Pollard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27518160/4848308)

Hope its helps!