# how to add shadow around the image in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to add a shadow around the Image my image is a rectangular field and i need to add a shadow around that rectangular field

I want to do something like this: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046810/how-to-add-shadow-around-circular-imageview)

I wanted to know how to do this in react native that can be applicable for both android and ios

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shadow is only for iOS. For Android you need Elevation. You could do something like this. I use it currently and works fine:

```js
elevationLow: {
    ...Platform.select({
    ios: {
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 2,    
    },
    android: {
        elevation: 5,
    },
    }),
},
```

Comment: Post your code, specially your styles. You must have a second view that is clearing your styles. In RN they are not inherited.

Comment: But elevation is not applicable to <Image /> component

Comment: @VincentDecaux You might have to use a wrapper and elevate a view where the Image resides.

Comment: You don't need to use platform.select.

Comment: Greate sharing !! also, you can follow this link https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/ to get the code if you want to have the exact code base of the volume of shadow needed

Answer (score 10):

Wrap your `Image` inside `View` (for semantic clarity) and then define following style rules to the *View*:

```
shadow: {
  shadowColor: '#202020',
  shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 0},
  shadowRadius: 5,
},
```

I made an example here: https://snack.expo.io/rJesdOgRZ. But atm "snack" is so freaking slow that it's difficult to check actual results. But at least the code is visible and works as a benchmark.

Comment: its not working in android I just followed what u suggested

Answer (score 7):

You can use `shadow` style props for your `View` to achieve this. You will want

`shadowOffset` = takes in `height` and (optional, i dont really like using it, but ) `width` values to move your shadow in those directions.

`shadowColor` = takes a colour, similar to `backgroundColor`, indicates colour of the shadow

`shadowRadius` = takes a value, will dictate how far out your shadow is from the View

`shadowOpacity` = value from 0 to 1, indicates how strong the shadow presence is.

Heres a quick example of something you probably want. This code will make a red circle, with a slight shadow visible at the bottom of the circle. This code is of course customizable.

```
<View style = {{
    position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 50, 
    backgroundColor: 'red', width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: { height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    }}>
    //CONTENT
</View>
```

Comment: Your welcome! See [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Shadow style props only works for ios, for android you can use elevation style prop and you provide any interger value from 1 to so on, as you required.

Comment: The elavtion prop is applicable only in android version 5.0 or above, so anke sure of it.

Comment: I am using 5.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

Another easiest and the best option I came across is the use of [react-native-shadow-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow-2) along with [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg). Here, we need to install react-native-svg since react-native-shadow-2 is dependant on react-native-svg.

**Basic shadow**

```
import { Shadow } from 'react-native-shadow-2'; 

export default const ImageWithShadow = () => {
    <Shadow> 
      <Image style={styles.imageStyles} source={ImageSource} />
    </Shadow>
}
```

**Advance shadow styling**

```
import { Shadow } from 'react-native-shadow-2'; 

export default const ImageWithShadow = () => {
    <Shadow startColor='#00000020' distance=10 radius=5 size=20> 
      <Image style={styles.imageStyles} source={ImageSource} />
    </Shadow>
}
```

As shown in the above sample code you have to just wrap all the content (image or text or View or any other react native component) that you need to add a shadow inside the   tag. No need of doing any manual styling like in react native shadow options. If you browse their documentation you can find many props that you can effectively utilize to customize the shadow applied to the component.