# Shadow resulting from elevation showing with circle drawable as background but not with rectangle

Tags: android, android-drawable, shadow

I'm trying to use a View's elevation property to cast a shadow. It works fine when the background is a circle or a rounded rectangle drawable. However, if I use a color or a rectangle drawable as a background the shadow doesn't show.

Simply changing the radius of the rounded rectangle to zero, causes the shadow to disappear. I have tried solutions to similar issues such as adding padding and margin. I added both:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

to the parent View but that didn't fix the problem either.

I am using the simplest shapes possible:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

And here's the very simple layout where I'm testing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
android:elevation="40dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know there are other ways of achieving shadows in Android such as using 9-patch images, but elevation is a much simpler way and I'm hoping to make it work using only that.

These are the previews changing only the background drawable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvace.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnCKu.png

This is the end result I'm going for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNyCp.png

But I mostly just want to figure out why the shadow is not showing with a color or rectangular drawable as background.

Answer (score 0):

When I use a solid color background (e.g. `android:background="#fff"`) or a rectangle shape without rounded corners and run the app, I see a shadow.

However, I have to actually *run the app*. Just looking at the Android Studio layout preview doesn't show the shadow unless I use a background drawable with rounded corners. So I suspect you're just looking at a bug (or feature?) of the layout preview.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped wrap my shape with `layer-list` like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/avatar_ripple">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/black_light" />
        <stroke
            android:width="@dimen/stroke_large"
            android:color="@color/gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Then you can simple apply `elevation` to your view with your drawable as background, but there is bug that you won't see the shadow until you launch the app.

Particularly helped this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60424218/16006976