# Elevation on non-rectangular background not working

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

I'm implementing a textview with BubbleMessage Background in Android.
 I have created the background with a NinePatchDrawable [(The image I used)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fglyi.png).

I want to change the elevation of the textview in the xaml so I set `android:elevation="30dp"` in the TextView, but after I did this I didn't get the wanted result. The result I got is: [Rectangular elevation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzqYP.png).

As you can see in the image I get the elevation not on the bubbleMessage itself but on the Rectangle that it is contained in.

I tried the solution that is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow) but it didn't help.

Comment: then draw the shadow by yourself, what `Drawable` class are you using as your `TextView:background`?

Comment: I use NinePatchDrawable on this example but I'm having problem using ShapeDrawable  as well.  With ShapeDrawable I can't see the elevation at all.

Comment: when you are using a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class you have a free hand and you can draw whatever you want in `draw` method

Comment: So I should add another drawable with the same shape but with some delta from the original shape?

Comment: for example, but you could also draw it by yourself like done in this Shape: https://gist.github.com/pskink/fe09aacd259f5cb050aa22691b294f1b

Comment: I didn't totally understand how to draw it by myself from the code. But the option I wrote works pretty good for me(even though not looking perfect).

Comment: just use [this](https://pasteboard.co/GFM4D0P.png) as a `Drawable source` and `Drawable mask`, `ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK)` as a `Drawable 
 shadow` and `8` as `float shadowRadius` and see how it looks like

Comment: It works! But What if my drawable is a NinePatchDrawable?

Comment: well, for NinePatchDrawable it could not work as it needs `getIntrinsicWidth` / `Height` - but you have the idea how it might be done - the best idea is debug step-by-step and see the `bitmap` in the debugger - it has the nice feature: `View Bitmap` or something similar