# elevation is not showing in GridView for material desgin

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, material-design

I had a GridView in which I want to show grid items with some elevation applied on them. I tried solution from this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow) but elevation is not shown while at runtime. The elevation is shown in preview builder.

My codes are

1. > fragment_grid.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:background="@drawable/grid_border"
       android:elevation="15dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:padding="4dp">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/backgroundImg"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="150dp"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:background="@drawable/image_border"
           android:elevation="1dp"
           android:src="@drawable/icon" />

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:padding="2dp">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="130dp"
               android:layout_height="40dp"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:padding="1dp">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/nameTV"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:maxLines="1"
                   android:text="Name"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/descriptionTV"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:maxLines="1"
                   android:text="Description" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/moreBtn"
               style="?android:attr/actionOverflowButtonStyle"
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="40dp"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
               android:foregroundGravity="center" />

       </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. > fragment_gird_activity.xml | 
   >   *This code is in RelativeLayout with android:gravity as center*

   ```
   <GridView
       android:id="@+id/fragmentGridView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:columnWidth="150dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
       android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
   ```
3. > GridAvtivity.java, it extends AppCompatActivity

   ```
   private GridView fragmentGridView;
   private DetailsBox adapter;
   private final ArrayList<Details> details = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.album_activity);

       fragmentGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_gird_activity);
       fillupData();
       adapter = new DetailsBox(getApplicationContext());
       fragmentGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

   class DetailsBox extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {

       private Context ctx;

       public DetailsBox(@NonNull Context context) {
           super(context, R.layout.fragment_grid, details);
           this.ctx = context;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, parent, false);
           Details detail = details.get(position);
           ((TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV)).setText(detail.getName());
           ((TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTV)).setText(detail.getDescription());
           return newView;
       }
   }


   private void fillupData() {
       details.add(new Details("Name 1", "Description 1"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 2", "Description 2"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 3", "Description 3"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 4", "Description 4"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 5", "Description 5"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 6", "Description 6"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 7", "Description 7"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 8", "Description 8"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 9", "Description 9"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 10", "Description 10"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 11", "Description 11"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 12", "Description 12"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 13", "Description 13"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 14", "Description 14"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 15", "Description 15"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 16", "Description 16"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 17", "Description 17"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 18", "Description 18"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 19", "Description 19"));
       details.add(new Details("Name 20", "Description 20"));
   }
   ```
4. > image_border.xml

[image: image_border.xml]

5. > grid_border.xml

[image: grid_border.xml]

Following produces this result in preview window
[image: Result in Preview Window]

and in runtime, this produces following result

[image]

Please help, I tried solutions form other threads but not able to add elevation at runtime.

Comment: just add some margin to the grid elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution - wrap your row layout to `cardView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/vCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <!-- Your row layout codes -->

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Wizard. this helped me.