# Relativelayout elevation cut off from bottom when other layout overlays this

Tags: android

Hi I am having problem in the xml design where I am using 3 RelativeLayout overlapping each other and I gave elevation to every layout. But elevation from the bottom is being cut off. I want to show the proper shadow. How can I do that. Please help

Here is xml code
https://hastebin.com/agarobojin.pl

Comment: If the *elevation* is 3dp then you will set the padding bottom of the RelativeLayout is 3dp as well.

Comment: @JohnLe Thanks for answering, I already doing that. please check my xml. I added it

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You should post a [mcve] as part of your question body to avoid link rot.