# Swipe Refresh Layout - How to re-adjust the elevation (shadow) of SRL?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I want to re-adjust the elevation of the `Swipe Refresh Layout`.

In `App Bar Layout` we can get the effect by calling `abl.setElevation(elevation);`.

Is it possible for the `Swipe Refresh Layout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SwipeRefreshLayout Documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout), it is possible.

It inherits the following method from `android.view.View` class:

`void setElevation(float arg0)`

So, I think it is possible for any view or layout which inherits `android.view.View` class.

Comment: But `swipeRefreshLayout.setElevation(elevation);` is not working for me. What should I do?

Comment: not working, as in showing error or not reflecting in the UI?

Comment: Not reflecting in the UI

Comment: try setting elevation along with a background color. I think only the shadow is not rendered.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955904/8112679

Comment: `android:background="@android:color/white"
android:elevation="10dp"` adding elevation to ouside of the container of `swipe refresh layout` but I want to elevate the round refershing view.