# How can I get a large drop shadow on a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been struggling with this for too long. I created a new Android project with a basic Activity, which comes with a button on a Fragment. My layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_other"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_first" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And whatever I try the button drop shadow never changes. Elevation, TranslationZ, changing themes...always just a slightly visible outline around the button.  I've tried everything posted on SO, like [this popular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow), and nothing works or alters the drop shadow. It seems like Google is FORCING buttons to not have drop shadows because textView drop shadows DO work. Here are 2 views a textview and a button with the same attributes:

[image]

The textview is on top, and has the drop shadow I want. So what's the trick? How can I get the same drop shadow on a button? BTW, when I press the button is does appear to have a drop shadow, but I want the button to have the drop shadow when NOT pressed.

PS. Annoyingly the button drop shadow appears in the layout design editor...but not when compiled and running on a device.

Comment: @WhatAJerk, That post suggests creating a fake shadow object and placing it behind the button. I cannot believe this would be the correct solution. That would not look good when animated or when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was correct, Google does treat buttons differently. The issue is an attribute called `stateListAnimator`. It appears to override elevation and translationZ making them useless. You can solve the problem by adding this line to your button XML:

`android:stateListAnimator="@null"`

then your elevation and translationZ attributes will work correctly. A better solution though it to create your own stateListAnimator. To do this create a directory called `animator` under your res folder and then add a new animator resource file to it called `button_with_shadow.xml`. Here's a sample that works well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="50"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="2dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="50"
                android:propertyName="textSize"
                android:valueFrom="15sp"
                android:valueTo="14sp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="false">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="50"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="10dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="50"
                android:propertyName="textSize"
                android:valueFrom="14sp"
                android:valueTo="15sp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="50"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="1dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="50"
                android:propertyName="textSize"
                android:valueFrom="15sp"
                android:valueTo="14sp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

It should be fairly easy to see what's happening here. Here's by button XML:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_other"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/button_with_shadow"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/myText" />
```