# Why is the Toolbar in the middle of the screen?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I am trying to use the toolbar using the [`Android Developers Guide`](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) for enabling material theming on pre-lollipop devices.

My app theme extends `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as so:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and `windowActionBar` is set to false as so:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#EEEEEE</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

My `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

but the toolbar appears in the middle of the screen rather than on top. What am I doing wrong?

`activity_main.xml:`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: you forgot to post activity_main.xml ... without its content it is not possible answer to this question

Comment: @Selvin Done! Posted the xml. I plan to add more to the XML. I am just starting.

Comment: use LinearLayout ... put Toolbar first then the SwipeRefreshLayout (or you wana Toolbar inside SwipeRefreshLayout ?)

Comment: @Selvin Oh as a rule of thumb, if I want it at the top, it must be the first view in the layout (inside the parent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your toolbar has nothing to do in the SwipeRefreshLayout

you have to use a LinearLayout (vertical) surrounding the Toolbar and SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
<Toolbar />
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
</SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The `Toolbar` is designed to be flat with no drop shadow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575197/no-shadow-by-default-on-toolbar
this comment could answer your question