# RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, layout

I want to add shadow to ToolBar and I use the following link:
[ToolBar Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575197/no-shadow-by-default-on-toolbar)

but running app show me this error in LogCat :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Toolbar code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolbarTheme"
    android:background="@drawable/main_header">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

MainActivity XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:text="ytkbhjk"/>
```

MainActivity Java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to make one more xml file which contains your toolbar:
Name of this xml is **toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Now change your relative layout's **include** tag like this

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in your activity, do something like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Where you use the `<include />` in your MainActivity XML, you should not put the `android:id="@+id/app_bar"`, but instead in the tag `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />`.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed `relativeLayout` instead just use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. And ts work.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading `android_m2repository_r29.zip` repository from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/ with instruction given in same.