# How to add view below the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

Is there a **simple way** to add view(s) below the toolbar, without compromising its current appearance? I just want to add an extra view right below the text of the toolbar. Note that toolbars have shadows and simply adding the view below the toolbar widget will not achieve what I want.

Comment: @Prachi I don't have any (yet).. I'm only using the default toolbar and just want to know how I can add view below its title's textview

Comment: same way  you add components into `Relative layout` or `linear layout`

Comment: @Prachi by doing that, the toolbar will add the view horizontally (between the title and the menu buttons) not vertically

Answer (score 4):

Add `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` in your `Toolbar` like:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
                        android:background="#ECA539"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

and then add `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in your `Relativelayout` like below:

```
<RelativeLayout

                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to do that.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_color"
    android:titleTextAppearance="@android:color/white"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- **** Place Your Content Here **** -->


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="My Content"/>

    <!-- **** This is your view that appears below toolbar **** -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
</FrameLayout></LinearLayout>
```

@toolbar_dropshadow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="#88333333"
    android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

For more information follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26904102/3907780

Answer (score 0):

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/custom_tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
         android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

//Add your components here
 </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: tried it out and it still appeared between the title and the menu buttons

Comment: post your xml and screenshot

Comment: The black area in the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/qwXmup5.jpg) is the view I'm adding

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in the above post was changing the layout the toolbar was in into a linear layout.

Whilst using frame layout, the views were places underneath the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the RelativeLayout, use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/custom_tool_bar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
android:gravity="center">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

//Add your components here, ie.:
<MyView android:id="@+id/black_box"
android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar" //relativity left or right available too
android:layout_width="match_parent"
etc.etc./>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`
```

I'm not sure why your toolbar is above the layout scope, but try it and let us know.