# Elevation is not working in ContraintLayout

Tags: android

I don't know why `android:elevation` is not working

My code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".UI.Activity.ChatActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text_messenger"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is your compile sdk version? elevation works for >21 versions.

Comment: On sdk version 28

Comment: Are you already using `android.support.design` library in your app? Also does elevation show without using ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Yes, i'm did `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

Comment: I try `RelativeLayout` but it's still not working

Comment: Do you want elevation below 21 version of android? What is your minimum sdk version?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Somehow elevation does not work until you set any background color to the `ViewGroup` or `View` in which you want to set elevation.

Set

```
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:elevation="2dp"
```

to LinearLayout in your above xml.

Answer (score 10):

This is default behaviour that shadow is **identified by some background**, so there will be **NO shadow** for **NO background**.

- Either set a background to your View.
- If your view does not have background. then you can set `android:outlineProvider="bounds"`.

#### Suggestion:

Both above solutions will work for Android versions >21.

**Solution for all versions**

You can put drawable shadow on Views.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Put **showdow.xml** in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="#33000000"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

[image: output]

You can find many ways to add shadow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26575197/6891563).

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this could be useful, previous solution unfortunally don't work for my case: I found a similar problem with material card do not showing elevation nor shadow if inside a constraintLayout (or not); I've solved both by valorizing other than cardElevation the layout_margin property, and with a value close to cardElevation, and making the latter not too high to avoid clipping.

```
android:layout_margin="5dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp"
```

I've a gist for material card inside a ConstraintLayout [here](https://gist.github.com/nadar71/006699e31ef7451813e6c97dacfbc5e2) and without it [here](https://gist.github.com/nadar71/d6bc6e0aa3189ff9264a116360b304fc)

Let me know if it works for you too.