# Android Lollipop preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar, android-support-library

Is there an easy way to create a preference like the system preferences in Lollipop?

My previous app had headers and fragments, but I want to use the AppCompat Toolbar and the PreferenceActivity (onBuildHeaders) can't use the new Toolbar. That's why I'm searching for a complete redesign of my preferences.

I want to do this:

[image]

Has someone any tutorial for this?

Comment: @DerGolem I added a screenshot, what I want be able to create...

Answer (score 1):

It' s simple. Just apply the Theme.AppCompat.xxx to your activity and put your `PreferenceFragment` in that activity if you use the Api level >= 11.

### EDIT

for the lastest supoort libary appcompat-v7, google provides `AppCompatDelegate` to do the trick, here is the [sample code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java) from google.

Comment: And how about headers? Everyone is talking about PreferenceFragments, but I need header xml files. This file can't be used in a Fragment. The header file was used to do the two pane view.

Comment: well, forgive my carefulness when reading your question, I thought you just need that toolbar... take a look at this, i suppose it' s helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564400/creating-a-preference-screen-with-support-v21-toolbar/26564401#26564401

Answer (score 0):

Try out my library: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary .

It lacks some of the stuff of the original API, but it's a good start... The hard part is to make it use a RecyclerView instead of a ListView, so that you could have multiple preferences on the same row. Then you'd need to also filter items as you type.