# What Is The Difference of AppCompatPreferenceActivity And SettingActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-preferences, android-settings

I add `SettingActivity` on my app, and I get this auto generated java files `AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java` and `SettingsActivity.java` .

**What's the difference of the two?** I came across with the link below but it doesn't discuss it.

[Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564400/creating-a-preference-screen-with-support-v21-toolbar)

I have no idea where to code.

Comment: `What's the difference of the two?` The former is compatible with older OS versions, too.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi - You mean the SettingsActivity is for older OS and AppCompatPreference is for API <= 21 ? Should I put my codes in both files, having the same code.

Comment: I mean the SettingsActivity is for **newer** OS. I should see the code for both. I'm still using Eclipse and targetting API Level 18 (I dislike Android Studio and API Level 19+)

Answer (score 3):

Look no need to create general_pref.xml if you want one page settings, I have created something for you to better understand (should work for you):

> res/xml/preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="pref_title_notifications"
        android:key="pref_category_notifications_key">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="notifications_on_off_key"
            android:title="pref_title_breaking_news_notification"/>

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notifications_sound_on_off_key"
            android:title="pref_title_enable_notifications_sound"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="pref_title_data"
        android:key="pref_category_data_key">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="pref_images_load_on_off_key"
            android:title="pref_title_load_images_on_mobile_data"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

> ActivitySettings.java

```
public class ActivitySettings extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedStateInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedStateInstanceState);

        // Display fragment as main content
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);  //load preference screen from xml directory.
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

*

> This is how Default SettingsActivity looks like in Tablet

*
[image]

> *and in Phone*

[image]

> After All changes your Tablet settings will look like Phone settings,
>   nothing else.Now Setting will look like Long list,instead of Headings,
>   You'll have categories. As you see, in last picture, category of
>   System Settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but my problem is how to get rid of the pref_header that is to be loaded as default. I created a SettingsActivity the one with template provided - which auto generated the AppCompatPrefences..

Comment: Replace your default SttingsActivity.java with with one in the post and preferences.xml with one in the post and just delete all other default pref_... xml including pref_header.xml. That should work. (If I got what you mean)

Comment: One last question, :) Thank you for the help and info - If I delete the pref_header.xml - it says that it is for tablet.

Comment: Look at the answer-above after the **EDIT**.

Comment: Thank you, I decided not to choose the template provided by AS. I manually create that one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems I am late to game, but anyway. HOpe this sill help.

> **1. Where to put your code (ANSWER)**

*SettingsActivity.java*

Do not mess with AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java. Every thing that you want to change should be coded inside SettingsActivity.java class.

> **2.What is AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java (ANSWER)**

Well when using settings activity the class to be created is like:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

In case we want to support upper versions of Android we use

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
```

I think you have seen this libraries android-support-v4,android-support-v7 and etc, They all are meant to support upper SDKs  (e.g version over 4, 7 and so on). And this class is kind of them.

Comment: FARID - Can I delete the pref_header and pref_notifications.xml ? and make a pref_general.xml .