# Add ActionBar to a PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-preferences

I am trying to make a `Settings` `Activity` using a `PreferenceActivity`. The problem is that the `ActionBar` won't show up no matter what I do.

I've tried `getSupportActionBar`, `getActionBar`, `setActionBar`. Nothing works. 
I see other apps settings with `ActionBar`s. Do they not use `PreferenceActivity`?

Comment: Yes, mostly people don't use PreferenceActivity for Activity that contains settings. I use normal Activity and handles everything on my own.

Comment: Check this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849193/how-to-add-action-bar-from-support-library-into-preferenceactivity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using an AppCompat theme, you have to pay attention to some points.

The `PreferenceActivity` **doesn't extend** the `AppCompatActivity` or the deprecated `ActionBarActivity`.

As solution you can create a `PreferenceFragment` as you are doing and **use it** in a standard `AppCompatActivity`. Of course you can use also a `Toolbar`.

Moreover with the new 22.1+ appcompat you can use the [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) to extend AppCompat's support to any Activity.

You can check this official link to [AppCompatPreferenceActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/58bf5b99e6132332afb8b44b4c8cedf5756ad464/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java), where you can find an example of this technique.

Answer (score 6):

***By explicitly themeing SettingActivity with a theme derived from DarkActionBar, we are able to add back the Action Bar.***

I did the same to have an action bar in my **Settings activity** and it worked for me .

1.First add a different style for your **Settings Activity** in styles.xml

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="AppTheme"/>
```

2.Then make a seperate **styles.xml** for the for version 21 (v21/styles.xml) as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Settings activity theme. -->
    <style name="SettingsTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/sunshine_blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/sunshine_dark_blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

3. At last in the ***AndroidManifest*** tag for your SettingsActivity you'll also want to add the settings theme:

   > android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"

This would add an action bar to your **Settings activity** in devices having android versions grater than or equal to 21.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me,

simply change **PreferenceActivity** to **AppCompatActivity** and in your manifest.xml file add `parentActivityName` for that particular activity.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"></activity>
```

**SettingsActivty.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();


    }


    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        }
    }
```