# How to use the v7/v14 Preference Support library?

Tags: android, android-support-library, support-preference

Together with the M release, there are new support libraries. One of them that seems to be very useful is the [v7 Preference Support](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-preference) library.

It does not seem to have `PreferenceActivity` or something similar, how do we integrate it to our app?

Comment: You have PreferenceFragment from the android.preference package right?

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T

Comment: https://github.com/codevscolor/MaterialPreference  I have implemented this  library that can be used to build material preference easily ( v7 preference compat is used here)

Comment: with `androidx`, it works about the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089561/549372

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You have to extend `AppCompatActivity`, which is required for fragment, and include a subclass of [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html). The abstract fragment requires to override one method, in which you should place your preference inflation logic. And last, your activity theme needs to specify a `preferenceTheme` attribute.

Read the announcement [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T). With preference-v7 library you can replace `PreferenceFragment` (API 11+) with `PreferenceFragmentCompat` subclass, and `SwitchPreference` (API 14+) with [`SwitchPreferenceCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SwitchPreferenceCompat.html) and have your settings screen work from API 7.

Below is how I made it work:

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }
}
```

**layout/activity_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <fragment
        android:name=".SettingsFragment"
        android:tag=".SettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

**xml/preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
        ...>

        <android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference
            ... />

        <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            ... />

        ...

    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>

    ...

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**preference-v7 default theme**

```
<style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">@style/Preference.PreferenceScreen</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">@style/PreferenceFragment</item>
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.Category</item>
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/Preference</item>
    <item name="preferenceInformationStyle">@style/Preference.Information</item>
    <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference</item>
    <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat</item>
    <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference</item>
    <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/PreferenceFragmentList</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @hidro Well. This does not work. It results in exception which boils down to: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment.

Comment: How can i use this v7.preference ?

Answer (score 12):

hidro's answer is right but one more thing here to notice:

**Just use normal preference xml tags such as `PreferenceScreen` instead of the full class name.** The support library will convert them automatically.

**Why:** If you use the full class name the code suggestion and layout preview will not work properly.

So you should write xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        ...>

        <ListPreference
            ... />

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            ... />

        ...

    </PreferenceCategory>

    ...

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: How do you know the tags will be replaced with support library counterparts?

Comment: @sfk92fksdf The source code is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/84765ea/v7/preference/src/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceInflater.java#216

The second parameter prefixes is in line 64 `init(PreferenceManager preferenceManager)` just like `setDefaultPackages(new String[] {"android.support.v7.preference."});`

Comment: interesting, thanks. Although I wouldn't rely on implementation details :-)

Answer (score 9):

With the new preference support library v7 you can use the [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html) with any `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

You have to set `preferenceTheme` in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  ...
  <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

In this way you can customize the `preferenceTheme` to style the layouts used for each preference type without affecting other parts of your Activity.

Comment: This is incorrect and caused me 30 minutes of headache. `PreferenceFragmentCompat` should not override `onCreate(Bundle b)`, it should override `onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s)`

Comment: @Cord Rehn: What was a reason of your headache? I have no problems overriding `onCreate` as for non-Preference fragment. `onCreatePreferences` is implemented too but has empty body. I am using `com.android.support:preference-v14:25.3.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right it doesn't exist on the appcompat v7, but Google actually added `AppCompatDelegate` abstract class as a delegate you can use to inject the AppCompat's support to any activity. You can find more from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849193/how-to-add-action-bar-from-support-library-into-preferenceactivity).

This is an example of how to inject the `AppCompatDelegate` into your activity from the AppCompat's samples from Google, You can find it [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/7200281446186c7192cb02f54dc2b38e02d705e5/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).

Comment: This is unrelated to the preference support library as native `PreferenceActivity` on which this `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` is based does not work in any way with classes introduced in `preference-v7` library. This method will only provide you with material themed widgets on all platforms but not consistent preference item looks - margins, font sizes, item layout in general.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement Hidro's answer above with an activity which also contained a toolbar and it gave me the following a layout inflation exception because of the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method
>       'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getContext()'
>       on a null object reference

I haven't been able to solve these, so have resorted to the following:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if(savedInstanceState == null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
  }
}
```

With the following layout for the SettingsActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Posted here as it may help if other people encounter the same exception