# PreferenceFragmentCompat crashes on initalization

Tags: android, android-support-library, preferencefragment, preference-v7

I have made an application with a ViewPager.
Everything is working fine, when I make a debug build, and test it on my phone. (Not emulator)
But when I build a release .apk and install it, the PreferenceFragmentCompat's *addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);* crashes the app.
[PreferenceFragmentCompat - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html#addPreferencesFromResource(int))

ApplicationSettingsFragment.java:

```
package hu.t_bond.homecontroller.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

import hu.t_bond.homecontroller.Launcher;
import hu.t_bond.homecontroller.R;

public class ApplicationSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(Launcher.SETTINGS_NAME);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s)
    {
    }
}
```

res/xml/preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="AutoUpdatesEnabled"
        android:title="@string/auto_updates_enabled"
        android:summary="@string/auto_updates_enabled_description"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And the crash report:

```
10-26 14:20:07.661 17763-17890/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: hu.t_bond.homecontroller, PID: 17763
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class PreferenceScreen
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:261)
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:280)
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.b(PreferenceInflater.java:289)
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:161)
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:117)
     at android.support.v7.preference.q.a(PreferenceManager.java:115)
     at android.support.v7.preference.j.b(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:366)
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.b.a.d(ApplicationSettingsFragment.java:18)
     at android.support.v4.b.o.h(Fragment.java:1942)
     at android.support.v4.b.ac.a(FragmentManager.java:1040)
     at android.support.v4.b.ac.b(FragmentManager.java:926)
     at android.support.v4.b.o.c(Fragment.java:882)
     at android.support.v4.b.an.b(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:152)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(ViewPager.java:1104)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(ViewPager.java:552)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(ViewPager.java:514)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.b(ViewPager.java:946)
     at android.support.v4.view.dw.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2910)
     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
     at android.support.v4.view.bo.c(PagerAdapter.java:276)
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.w.c(Launcher.java:948)
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.Launcher.a(Launcher.java:521)
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.q.onClick(Launcher.java:663)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:248)
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:280) 
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.b(PreferenceInflater.java:289) 
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:161) 
     at android.support.v7.preference.p.a(PreferenceInflater.java:117) 
     at android.support.v7.preference.q.a(PreferenceManager.java:115) 
     at android.support.v7.preference.j.b(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:366) 
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.b.a.d(ApplicationSettingsFragment.java:18) 
     at android.support.v4.b.o.h(Fragment.java:1942) 
     at android.support.v4.b.ac.a(FragmentManager.java:1040) 
     at android.support.v4.b.ac.b(FragmentManager.java:926) 
     at android.support.v4.b.o.c(Fragment.java:882) 
     at android.support.v4.b.an.b(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:152) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(ViewPager.java:1104) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(ViewPager.java:552) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(ViewPager.java:514) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.b(ViewPager.java:946) 
     at android.support.v4.view.dw.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2910) 
     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37) 
     at android.support.v4.view.bo.c(PagerAdapter.java:276) 
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.w.c(Launcher.java:948) 
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.Launcher.a(Launcher.java:521) 
     at hu.t_bond.homecontroller.q.onClick(Launcher.java:663) 
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

And I'm using the newest libs:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.0'
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: try to use res-auto instead of res/android

Comment: @Fakher the same problem.

Comment: ok try to remove all the upperCase : preferencescreen

Comment: @Fakher no: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class (not found)preferencescreen`

Comment: from where did you get this code ?!!
<PreferenceScreen> tag is not a default XML tag in android !!!

Comment: It is from the support  library. I added the link to the description.

Comment: what's your build tool and your compileSDK ???

Comment: @Fakher Gradle 2.4 Build Tools Version 23.0.1 Compile SDK version: 23 (And I'm using Android Studio 1.5 Preview 2)

Comment: @T-bond do you have ProGuard on when building your APK?

Comment: @Marko THANK YOU!! That fixed it. Put in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP said he is using ProGuard when building his APK file.

As [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183261&can=1&q=label%3AComponent-Support-Libraries%20status%3AFutureRelease&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) bug report states

> Make sure your proguard configuration contains a line like this:

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.preference.Preference
```

This might be the issue, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Because of you imported `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`, so you need `<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen .../>` and `<android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference .../>`. It will looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="AutoUpdatesEnabled"
        android:title="@string/auto_updates_enabled"
        android:summary="@string/auto_updates_enabled_description"
        android:defaultValue="true" />

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

More information about these [new preference types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/package-summary.html) which is supported for v7 Support Library.

**EDIT**

Instead of overriding default `onCreate(Bundle)` method, but you should only override `onCreatePreferences(Bundle, String)`:

```
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Comment: How could I missed that? :D
But after repleacing the problem is the same:
`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen`
(But the developer site said that I should use that way. And it worked in debug release)
Maybe the ProGuard?

Comment: @T-bond, I edited my answer, and see what happens now.

Comment: the problem is the same. :'(
Doesn't the `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` could be a point to start of?

Comment: @T-bond how are you using your SettingsFragment? Do you maybe host it inside a layout via `<fragment>` tag?

Comment: No. My *FragmentStatePagerAdapter* has: `@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) { return new ApplicationSettingsFragment(); }`
The return statement in a switch with other fragments, and they are working correctly.

Comment: @T-bond, this post may helps you a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32919694/3922207

Comment: @AnggrayudiH there is nothing new in the link for me I think.

Answer (score 2):

### Fixing all proguard issues for the most recent androidx

```
-keep public class * extends androidx.preference.* { *;}
```

Comment: Why would this fix issues? Is there a bug report for this specifically?

Answer (score -1):

try to add this constructor in your java code:

```
    PreferenceFragmentCompat(){
this.super();
    // a code
    }
```

Comment: I have added: `public ApplicationSettingsFragment() {
        super();
    }` but the problem is the same.

Comment: just try to add this constructor, it's mentionated in android developers, just check the link in your description

Comment: But I can't add your code, because it is not my class'es constructor.
I have added a default constructor to my class, and called super(), because this.super() neither allowed there. But where do you find that information on the link?

Comment: Yes. As you see in the description, 23.1.0 :)

Comment: that's really strange !! plz tell me what was the pblm if u find the solution !!