# PreferenceFragmentCompant showing null in onCreatePreferences on rootKey

Tags: android, preferencefragment, preferencescreen

I am having a problem with `PreferenceFragmentCompat` while trying to develop `nested` settings for my `android` application. I have `Fragment` called Settings `Fragment` where I have following method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        Log.d("KEY", rootKey + "KEY");
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main, rootKey);
    }
```

However, when I run the application I always get null to Logcat. Here is my pref_main.xml which have nested PreferencesScreen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="test">
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="button_voicemail_category_key"
        android:title="test"
        android:persistent="false">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="Default value"
            android:key="edit_text_preference_1"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:title="Edit text preference" />
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="check_box_preference_1"
        android:title="Check box preference" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Do you have any idea where the problem lies, because I tried many different things but couldn't find a solution for the problem.

I am looking forward to your response!

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070186/how-to-use-the-v7-v14-preference-support-library), make sure you're inheriting from AppCompatActivity, etc. What exactly do you mean by "I always get null to Logcat?" Can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstood the meaning of the `rootKey`. 
Reading the documentation it says

> **String**: If non-null, this preference fragment should be rooted at the `PreferenceScreen` with this key.

That means if your `PreferenceScreen` is your main `PreferenceScreen`, in your case the Screen with the key attribute `test`, the `rootKey` is set to `null`. For the child screens, which gonna be open differently, the `rootKey` will be set to `test`, since those are the childs of the `PreferenceScreen` with the key `test`.

However, your should have a look on [the current guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#preferencescreens). It says:

> Declaring nested hierarchies within the same XML resource using a nested `<PreferenceScreen>` is no longer supported. You should use nested `Fragment` objects instead.

See also: [onCreatePreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat#onCreatePreferences(android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)) and [Organizing your settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#preferencescreens)