# PreferenceActivity: getFragmentManager() has been deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, deprecation-warning, androidx

When testing a [android.preference.PreferenceActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity), I get the following warning:

> warning: [deprecation] getFragmentManager() in Activity has been deprecated

That is how I obtain a handle to the current `PreferenceFragment`:

```
FragmentManager fm = this.mActivity.getFragmentManager();
this.currentFragment = (PreferenceFragment) fm.getFragments().get(1);
```

Using `FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` is obviously not an option.

I've found [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat), which would replace the deprecated `PreferenceFragment`.

But is there any `androidx` replacement for the `PreferenceActivity`?

Comment: Good question, it may be bug in documentation of Android Class. You should post a bug on Google Issues Tracker. Obviously using `getSupportFragmentManager` is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've came up with is an `AppCompatActivity`, which inflates `androidx` [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragment). I've kept the previous `EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT`, so that switching to a specific `PreferenceFragment` still would work. `EXTRA_NO_HEADERS` has not yet been considered:

```
/**
 * Preference {@link AppCompatActivity}.
 * @see <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference Fragment">PreferenceFragment</a>
**/
public final class PreferenceCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** the class-name of the main {@link androidx.preference.PreferenceFragment} */
    public static final String MAIN_FRAGMENT = "com.acme.fragment.PreferencesFragment";

    /** framework {@link Intent} extra */
    public static final String EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT = ":android:show_fragment";

    /** framework {@link Intent} extra */
    public static final String EXTRA_NO_HEADERS = ":android:no_headers";

    /** the currently displayed {@link PreferenceFragment} */
    private PreferenceFragment currentFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String fragmentName = MAIN_FRAGMENT;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT) != null) {
            fragmentName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT);
        }
        this.switchToFragment(fragmentName, null);
    }

    private void switchToFragment(String fragmentName, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        PreferenceFragment fragment;
        switch(fragmentName) {
            // case "": {break;}
            default: {
                fragment = new PreferencesFragment();
            }
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        this.currentFragment = fragment;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.NONE)
    public PreferenceFragment getCurrentFragment() {
        return this.currentFragment;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

**Update**: Meanwhile there's [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat), which support this by default.

Answer (score 3):

The Fragment-related UI classes that ship as part of the device firmware have been deprecated in Android 28. It is recommended to move to the support library classes for `Activity`s and `Fragment`s.

There are already other posts about this:

- [Since the Android getFragmentManager() API is deprecated, is there any alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737667/since-the-android-getfragmentmanager-api-is-deprecated-is-there-any-alternati)
- [How to use the v7/v14 Preference Support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070186/how-to-use-the-v7-v14-preference-support-library)