# Why are API 28 platform resources not available?

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx

**TL;DR:**

This line compiles:

```
int resid = android.R.layout.preference_category;
```

But this line does not:

```
int resid = android.R.layout.preference;
```

The error is "cannot find symbol variable preference". But both resources are clearly available in the `Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res\layout` directory!

Why does this happen?

**Background**

I can navigate (in the IDE) to the `preference_category` resource, and sure enough, the `preference.xml` layout is right next to it, along with about a thousand other layouts that, similarly, will not compile.

My build.gradle (excerpt):

```
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
}
```

I recently switched my app over to AndroidX. For the most part, everything went smoothly, except I noticed my preferences had new visual styles. I wouldn't care, except that I had "subclassed" `preference.xml` by copying the original Android layout, making a trivial change, and then specifying that layout in my `prefs.xml`, e.g.:

```
...
<androidx.preference.CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_audio"
    android:title="Audio"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:layout="@layout/my_custom_preference"
    />
...
```

Preferences that I've handled in this way still look like they used to -- the way they looked *before* I switched to AndroidX. But all the other preferences now look drastically different.

I went back to the API level 28 folder, and checked the contents of Android's original `preference.xml`, to see if it had changed (since I originally copied/subclassed it). It has not! Yet, the styles of the preferences have changed.

To troubleshoot, I tried to verify that `android.R.layout.preference` was actually pointing to the resource I was looking at, which led me to the above mentioned compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use the framework's preferences (incl. resource `android.R.layout.preference_category`), but [androidx.preference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference). This also features a new one [PreferenceManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager.html), which should be used instead. Mixing up `android.preference` with `androidx.preference` may lead to unexpected results. Once posted one custom [PreferenceCompatActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078533/preferenceactivity-getfragmentmanager-has-been-deprecated/53089561#53089561), which might be a suitable starting-point.

Comment: This answer set me on the right path. I didn't realize that androidx had its own layout resources which are different from the platform resources. I still don't understand why I can't refer to a resource that is present in the platform sdk, but that is less important now. Thank you.

Comment: @greeble31 `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` should both be 28 or 29... and inflating a `Preference` into a `CheckboxPreference` is questionable, because there is no check-box contained.