# Insert actionBar in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I created a single activity setting with a preferenceFragment with the following source:

```
package com.ocsaram.vdchorta;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
            new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings_preference, false);
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

   
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preference);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        

    }
}
```

}

This is the file setting_preference.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="sample_key"
        android:title="Title"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:summary="ciao"/>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="sample2_key"
        android:title="Title 2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:summary="ciao"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now I would like to add an actionBar in the PreferenceFragment only that I'm not succeeding. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance for the help.
Greetings.

Comment: Related post - [How to add Action Bar from support library into PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17849193/465053)

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate()` method, you can actually include the following snippet:

```java
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("YourTitle");
}
```

This will automatically add the actionbar, which will also include the title as defined in `.setTitle("YourTitle")` as well as the 'back' button on the top left of the actionbar as defined by `.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.