# Use ActionBar from support library in SettingsActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am using support library to show action bar by extending my MainActivity by **ActionBarActivity**. It is working correctly but now I have created a SettingActivity which extends **PreferenceActivity** , as multiple inheritance is not supported in Java so how can I use ActionBar in SettingsActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Searched the net for it. I don't think there is a thing for both the preference activity AND action bar activity. I found this though, if you really want to add an action bar to your preference activity
[ActionBar in PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928874/actionbar-in-preferenceactivity)